# how to update a git branch to other branch?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git

I have two branches, `master` and `test`.

The test branch hasn't been updated for a long time.

Now I want the test branch to have the same file with master, without merge, because merge is bringing too many conflicts. I just want the branch test to have the same file like master while retain it's past commits. Then I can make some modification based on the test branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain you changes on `test`, the easiest thing would be to rebase it on top of `master` (but, of course, you'd need to handle any merge conflicts):

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/someproject [test] $ git rebase master
```

If you want to discard all your changes in test, you could just drop this branch and create a new one from master:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/someproject [master] $ git branch -D test
Deleted branch test (was a046456).
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/someproject [master] $ git branch test
```